# TUG 2020 is going online July 24, 25 and 26th

Tags: discussion, conferences

## TUG 2020 announcement

> The 41st annual TeX user conference **(TUG 2020)** is going digital on July 24, 25, 26. Register **for free!**

### Introduction

As we move TUG 2020 completely online, we look forward to offering you the same vibrant programming, innovative and timely content from presenters, and opportunities to reflect and connect over the emerging topics in TeX and typography with users across the world. The online conference will include our regular offerings and opportunities for engagement, including sessions, workshops, keynotes, and space to connect with users, from across the globe.

In addition to participating in the live event, all attendees will have access to break-out rooms for networking and social engagement. Moving our face-to-face conference to a fully online format presents us with the unique opportunity to spotlight the best of what the online modality affords – meaningful collaboration and the ability to reflect and connect with colleagues around the world. We hope that you will join us for this reimagined event, and celebrate our collective resilience and dedication to forging connections without boundaries.

We look forward to welcoming you to the TUG 2020 Online Conference in July, and we are here to help you however we can with questions and requests for support.  Please feel free to reach out to us with requests related to TUG 2020 at `tug-conferences@tug.org`.

### Registration

Registration is required. While access to the meeting will be free to everyone, you will be required to register to view the meeting. Registration for the meeting is open at the [event website](https://tug.org/tug2020/).

*PN, on behalf of the TUG 2020 Organizing Committee*

[image: TUG 2020 Poster]

Comment: @Paulo To increase visibility for this topic, may I repost this as blog post on https://topanswers.xyz/tex ?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Of course! Please do.

Comment: Done https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1135 Thanks a lot!

Comment: The conference website mentions live streams on YouTube – will these also be available for viewing later?

Comment: Yes, these will be processed and available for viewing later.

Comment: So is there still bowling at TUG meetings?